# Java zip files and directories into one archive

Tags: java, file, directory, compression, zip

I have the following file structure:

```
C:/test/example1/file1.txt
C:/test/file2.txt
C:/test/file3.txt
```

How can I archive those files and directories so that the resulting zip looks like that:

```
Archive.zip
     example
          file1.txt
     file2.txt
     file3.txt
```

Like WinRar would do when selecting multiple files and folders to compress.

Code:

```
Path baseDir = Paths.get(content.toString());
Path zipPath = Paths.get(mainJarDir.toString());
Map<String, ?> env = Collections.singletonMap("create", "true");
URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipPath.toUri());

try {
  final FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  try {
    MoreFiles.copyRecursive(baseDir, zipfs.get("/"), RecursionMode.FAIL_FAST, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
  } 
  catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is done using [one of my packages](https://github.com/fge/java7-fs-more):

```
final Path baseDir = Paths.get("c:\\test");

final Path zipPath = Paths.get("path/to/zipfile");
final Map<String, ?> env = Collections.singletonMap("create", "true");
final URI uri = URI.create("jar:" + zipPath.toUri());

try (
    final FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
) {
    // in java7-fs-more
    MoreFiles.copyRecursive(baseDir, zipfs.getPath("/"), RecursiveMode.FAIL_FAST);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but isn't there a way without using a library?

Comment: There can be but this would require writing a `FileVisitor` and `Files.walkFileTree()`. Plus you'd have to deal with paths from different providers... All things which this library does for you already so why hesitate? :p Plus, it's light

Comment: yeah so I will give the library a try :) Thank you!

Comment: So what's up with the "(" after the try statement? I get an error on it. Can I just replace it with a standart try/catch block ?

Comment: That's a try-with-resources statement. Don't you use Java 7+?

Comment: I am using java 8.25 in Processing, so that could be the problem. Another problem I have: what is `zipfs.getPath("/")` ?

Comment: That's not a problem at all, since Java 8 by definition supports everything Java 7 supports. It looks like your project is not configured to use Java 8 as a language level. As to `zipfs.getPath("/")` it gets the root path out of the zip filesystem created.

Comment: Ok, but where is `zipfs` declared? Also I get a UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Well, in the try with resources block... And `UnsupportedOperationException` on what? Without the actual code it's impossible to diagnose anything

Comment: Hey, you completely botched my code. This is not at all the code I provided. I told you to change the language level of your project to Java 8. If your IDE does not understand the try-with-resources statement, it means the language level is set to 6 or lower. Fix your IDE and run my code exactly.

Comment: Have also a look at [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9TFPiUobW8) which I made about try-with-resources

Comment: Processing is using 1.7.0_72 as JDK

Comment: Then change the language level to Java 7. But run my code unchanged. The code you have written will not work for obvious reasons.

Comment: `String p = System.getProperty("java.version") + " | " +
System.getProperty("java.home") + " | " +
System.getProperty("java.vendor") + " | " +
System.getProperty("java.vendor.url");
System.out.println(p);` returns `1.7.0_72 | /Applications/Processing.app/Contents/PlugIns/jdk1.7.0_72.jdk/Contents/Home/jre | Oracle Corporation | http://java.oracle.com/`

Comment: Again: run my code. Yours does not use try-with-resources. And again: fix your IDE so that it uses Java 7 as a language level.

Comment: Again: My IDE is running JDK 1.7.0_72 as selected in the settings menu. And try-with-resources are not working, IDE is excepting {, found '('

Comment: Again: there is a language level for a project; and for your particular project, it is set to 6, not 7. Otherwise it wouldn't tell that `(` is not supported.

Comment: I don't even have java 6 installed (yes I removed it from os x)

Comment: Don't be so stubborn and look at your project settings. And do note that Java 7 will be able to parse and compile all previous versions of the language.

Comment: I am able to import java.util.Objects which has been added in JDK 1.7. And my settings are set to use JDK 1.7.0_72

Comment: Which (again, #4) does not mean that your _language level_ is set to 7